# Balloon flyto Google Earth API

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin

In my KML I have an aggregate of placemarks in a table format. When you click the placemark you can see all the placemarks currently being loaded. Each of the placemarks have an id like below

```
<Placemark id="Location1">
```

When I add the following below I am able to fly to that balloon and it will open. However in the API this function does not work. It tries to do the following http://www.something.com#ballooonFlyTo is there a way to allow the balloon fly to method in the API?

```
<a href="#Location1;balloonFlyto>Location 1</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly no, but it would be easy to modify your links to call a custom function that will support the behavior you require.

Also, if you are loading your features via kml rather than creating them programmatically then you would need to supply the *full path* to the kmlFeature - not just its ID. i.e.

`http://somesite.com/my.kml#Location1` rather than just `#Location1` - where `http://somesite.com/my.kml` is the file that defines the feature with the id `Location1`.

If you have something like the following javascript method it should work as expected. That is it will fly to the view and open a feature balloon. (This is presuming `ge` is the google earth plugin in your application and that the placemarks have abstract views defined).

```
// Attempts to find and element by ID,
// fly to its abstract view and open a feature balloon for it.
var flyto = function(id) {
  var placemark = ge.getElementByUrl(id);
  if(!placemark) {
    return false;
  }

  if (placemark.getAbstractView()) {
   ge.getView().setAbstractView(placemark.getAbstractView());
  }

  var content = placemark.getBalloonHtmlUnsafe(); // or getDescription()
  var balloon = ge.createHtmlStringBalloon('');
  balloon.setFeature(placemark);
  balloon.setContentString(content);
  ge.setBalloon(balloon);

  return false;
};
```

Then you can simply modify your links to call the `flyto` function passing the desired id. e.g.

`<a href="javascript:flyto('http://somesite.com/my.kml#Location1');">Location 1</a>`

If your placemarks do not have abstract views, then you would have to do something like extracting the point geometry and then create a `lookat` or `camera` using the latitude and longitude data to set the view.

**EDIT**

I decided that this functionality was really cool, so I have put together an example that does not require any special mark up of the links at all. When kml links containing a command are clicked the plugin behaves just like the full Google Earth Client would.

Here is a  [fully working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fraser/8t8mK/).

Comment: Fraser,
Thanks for the replies to my thread. I have followed your work for some time on GE. I owe a lot to you for you previous questions and answers. I tried the code you provided however the <a href="javascript:flyto('http://somesite.com/my.kml#Location1');">Location 1</a> does not show as a Hyperlink in the API however it does for the EC. Any ideas

Comment: Hey, not sure what you mean by `does not show as a Hyperlink in the API however it does for the EC`? Where are you trying to put it? Are you tring to place the `<a>` link  in a balloon, rather than the HTML page or something? If so use `getBalloonHtmlUnsafe` rather than `getDescription`

Comment: I am adding that '<a href="javascript:flyto('http://somesite.com/my.kml#Location1');">Location 1</a>' into a balloon in a CDATA tag

Comment: This is due to content scrubbing. Easy to fix, see my edit, simply use `getBalloonHtmlUnsafe` rather than `getDescription`

Comment: Please see the edits - I made two working examples, one based on the idea discussed, and one that is much more generic and doesn't require `javascript:` links in the kml or html.

Comment: Here is the code I am using. It is only the Javascript.
http://jsbin.com/aWowamad/1/

Comment: I am experiencing 2 issues with the first code. I get false when I click on the flyto. Second I have another KML that is loaded which outlines all the countries in the world and states. Usually I can grab the globe anywhere the KML outlines and spin it without a balloon showing. However now if for example I place the cursor over Colorado and try to grab the globe it shows the balloon first then spins. Before the new code I was able to spin the globe then click on the state for the balloon. hope that makes sense. I think I was able to isolate it to the `balloon.setFeature(feature)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43358/discussion-between-fraser-and-jeremya1)

Comment: The second example is parsing the KML into XML format in a new window.
In addition the I get an error on this part of the script
`$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document.body).on('click', '.kml', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ge.setBalloon(null);
        var query = parseQuery(this.href);
        var feature = getFeature(query.Path, query.ID);
        window[query.Command](feature);
    });
});`

It says object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: You just need to include jQuery (see the frameworks on the fiddle page). You can simply add this line to the head of your page to do this. `<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>`.

Comment: I have jquery.min.1.10.2 does it need to be 1.9.1?